# How to get Monitoring monitoring data of other projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP support staff

My name is Hotta.

There is an environment described in "I. Configuration".
What is the best way to achieve "II. what i want to do is .." in this environment?
Please tell us about the recommended implementation method.

## 1. Configuration

### 1-1. Project owned by Company A account

(1) There is one VPC, and the VM instance of the monitoring server is installed in it.

(2) This monitoring server exchanges data via API via HTTPS communication. Webhook communication is also possible.

### 1-2. Project owned by Company B account

(1) There is one VPC, and a VM instance to be monitored is installed.

(2) This VM monitors CPU / memory resources with Cloud Monitoring

## 2. what i want to do is ..

### 2-1.

Resource data collected by monitoring the B company project
I want to get it regularly from the monitoring server of company A's VPC as a pull type.

### 2-2

I want to communicate securely in a private environment for the above communication.
I don't want to go through the internet.

## 3. Question

### 3-1. Question

Please tell me how to achieve the above.

### 3-2. Question

Is it possible to connect company A VPC and company B VPC by VPC peering and acquire data on company B's monitoring from company A's virtual server only by private IP communication?
Monitoring is a global service and I don't think it can be acquired because it is not in the VPC ...

Thank you.

Comment: `GCP support staff` <-- that's not us.

Answer (score 0):

When using a VPC peering if you need to reach other destinations within the current or peered VPC traffic will never go to the [internet](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) to reach another VPC resource.

Regarding the second point Instances without public IP can always send their data to Cloud Monitoring by enabling Private Google Access on the [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#enabling-pga) traffic sent trough PGA would not leave GCP as the routes for PGA are not being [advertised on the internet](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config-routing), and to have all the data available from a single Workspace both workspaces can be [merged together](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/manage#merge-account), however after both are merged they are only accessible via the host workspace.